# Change the way lightning:inputLocation looks

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I want to change the way **lightning:inputLocation** looks, when i use it without 'slds-input' class it looks like this

[image: lightning:inputLocation without 'slds-input']

when I use it with 'slds-input' class it looks like this
[image: lightning:inputLocation with 'slds-input']

but I want to make it look something like this[image: image of ui:inputDateTime]

**where latitude and longitude are in same line**(this image is of ui:inputDateTime where date and time are shown in same line/row)

when i inspected it, it's html code turned out to be

```
<fieldset class="slds-form-element">
    <legend class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-title_caps">Doctor's Office Location</legend>
    <div class="slds-form-element__group">
        <div class="slds-form-element__row">
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                <lightning-input data-latitude="">
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label for="input-5" class="slds-form-element__label slds-no-flex">Latitude</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-grow">
                            <input type="text" id="input-5" class="slds-input">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                <lightning-input data-longitude="">
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <label for="input-6" class="slds-form-element__label slds-no-flex">Longitude</label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-grow">
                            <input type="text" id="input-6" class="slds-input">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

is there any way to change it to horizontal from vertical view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer the Compound variant of [Form Layout](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-layout/#content) example from SLDS documentation.

To get the desired output you need to enclose the fieldset in a div with classes `slds-form slds-form_compound`:

```
<div class="slds-form slds-form_compound">
    <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
        <legend class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-title_caps"
            >Doctor's Office Location</legend>
        <div class="slds-form-element__group">
            <div class="slds-form-element__row">
                <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-01">Latitude</label>
                    <input type="text" id="input-01" class="slds-input" />
                </div>
                <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-02">Longitude</label>
                    <input type="text" id="input-02" class="slds-input" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

---

Added by [Sumuga](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/18270/sumuga):

Something like this should do the trick

```
<lightning:inputLocation label="My Coordinates" latitude="37.7938460" 
    longitude="-122.3948370" class="slds-form slds-form_compound"/>
```

**Output:**

[image: Horizontal]